# How to take Asp.net website offline in iis 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET website, but I would like to show an "under maintenance" page when my clients try to visit the site. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 40):

> If you are running your application within a .NET 4.0 application pool (IIS 7.0 or IIS 7.5) or your web site is configured as an ASP.NET 4.0 web site (IIS 6.0) and would like to show your clients an "under maintenance" page for a limited time, the easiest way is to put a file named app_offline.htm in your web site's root folder. Then your application will be taking offline and the clients will be served with app_offline.htm page whatever their requests are.
>
> When you are done with maintenance, just remove or rename the file and everything goes back to normal.

Source: [Easiest way to take your web site offline (IIS 6.0 or IIS 7.5 with .NET 4.0)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2012/02/03/easiest-way-to-take-your-web-site-offline-iis-6-0-or-iis-7-5-with-net-4-0.aspx)

Comment: here i am confused, i have my asp.net application under inetpub\wwwroot\test     should i include app_ffline.html page inside test folder or set as a default document, really confused on this

Comment: @user3770612: putting the file on `inetpub\wwwroot\test` should be enough

Comment: i have just created app_offline.html file in test folder but still i am able to see my actual webpage and not the under maintenance page

Comment: @user3770612: rename it to `app_offline.htm`, without `l` at the end.

Comment: Thanks @claudio it worked, but is there any other way to do the same job or this way is standard

Comment: @user3770612: this is the standard way

Comment: Creating `app_offline.htm` and placing it in the root folder of the application has done the job for me.

Comment: the source link is down. any update

Comment: @MaythamFahmi: the link is down but the content of the source link is written in the answer.