# How do I redirect MVC to a under maintenance page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I am using Asp.net MVC. I am trying to do some maintenance on my website and want to put up a web page as such. I am using IIS10 under W2016.

My url usually looks something like:

https://mywebsite.com/CustPortal/Account/Logon/23ef306d-488a-4082-8384-4b6d5b5e315c/

The guid on the end is used to verify the customer. Anyhow, I changed the folder in IIS to point to another folder for now and it works if the customer visits:

https://mywebsite.com/CustPortal/Account/Logon/

If the guid is on the end, which is the majority of the time, the webpage isn't found. I cannot account for each guid and create a folder for it.

Is there a way in IIS to display a page regardless of the link they are given? So that when they visit mywebsite.com it displays that it's under maintenance regardless of the `/CustPortal/Account/Logon/23ef306d-488a-4082-8384-4b6d5b5e315c/` that is at the end?

Thanks!

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25307834/1663001

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the quick response. I just tried this and it had no affect. I actually put it in every folder I had just to make sure. I did notice that it says it is for IIS 6.0, IIS 7.5 with .NET 4.0. I am using IIS10. Not sure if it suppose to work for that version.

Comment: you can use `_ViewStart.cshtml` file to detect an valid guid and show an appropriate message.  Or your `AccountController.Logon` action.  There are many options available.